# iOS Development Certificate Expires in 30 Days

Tags: ios, certificate

Recently i got an email saying that my iOS Development Certificate will no longer be valid in 30 days. To generate a new certificate, sign in and visit Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles.

**Certificate: iOS Development**
**Team ID: ***********.**

So, what exactly I need to do?
I think I need to pay for next year right?
and I already checked(Enabled) Auto-Renew Membership so what will happened after 30 days??
is my apps on there app-Store are stay as it is?

and why I got this mail because still 2 months are remaining for Expiration Date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's your development certificate.  If you have Xcode managing your certificates for you then it can fix it automatically when it expires.  If you want to do it manually, go to the [Apple Developer Portal](https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/development/create) and make a new one:

[image: Dev Portal Add Dev Certificate]

Once you make it, you can download it and double-click it to add it to your Keychain and make it available for use.